# Rapidly searching the internet with small breaks

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sometimes, I have a lot of things I want to ask the Internet, so I decided to make my searches go faster with some automation...

But I think this could be programmed better, even though I think it's pretty compact.

```
from subprocess import call

with open("C:\\Users\\Andy\\Desktop\\queries.txt").read().splitlines() as f, 0 as i:

 while True:

  if (((not i) + i) % 2) != 0:

    call('start firefox.exe https://duckduckgo.com/?q=' + f[i].replace(" ", "+"), shell=True)

  else:

    call('start firefox.exe https://duckduckgo.com/?q=' + f[i].replace(" ", "+"), shell=True)

    call('timeout 120')

  i += 1
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate - So... Is this question good? You got an answer? If you downvoted, can I get a reversal? ... Basically commenting to bump this post...

Comment: Reversed. Give me a few hours to get stuff done and I can make some suggestions.

Comment: This code is still broken. `0 as i` causes exception because numbers can't be used in context managers.

Comment: And `...splitlines() as f` seems broken too, since that would be using a list in a context manager. Again, we need working code to review. This won't run.

Answer (score 2):

This code still doesn't work.

```
with open("C:\\Users\\Andy\\Desktop\\queries.txt").read().splitlines() as f, 0 as i:
```

will cause two errors since lists and integers don't have an `__enter__` method.

I still know roughly what you're going for though, so I can make some suggestions about the rest of the code.

---

Even if `0 as i` did work, that would be an abuse of `with`. If you want to define a variable, just use the typical `i = 0` syntax.

---

Your condition in the `if` is far over complicated. Running it, the intent seems to be just to check if a number is odd or zero. That can be made much simpler:

```
if i % 2 == 1 or i == 0:
```

---

You duplicate

```
call('start firefox.exe https://duckduckgo.com/?q=' + f[i].replace(" ", "+"), shell=True)
```

in each branch of the `if`. That's not necessary though. Really, that whole check is just so you can add a timeout if `i` is even. That bit can be reduced down to

```
while True:
    call('start firefox.exe https://duckduckgo.com/?q=' + f[i].replace(" ", "+"), shell=True)

    if i % 2 == 0 and i != 0:
        call('timeout 120')

    i += 1
```

---

You could also get rid of the need for `i += 1` but iterating over a [count](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) object instead. It's basically an infinite `range`:

```
for i in count():
    call('start firefox.exe https://duckduckgo.com/?q=' + f[i].replace(" ", "+"), shell=True)

    if i % 2 == 0 and i != 0:
        call('timeout 120')
```

Of course though, this maintains the impossible condition that `f` is a file of infinite length.

Comment: Since you've just answered, and thank you for that, should I update the question with working code, or does that change the question too much? ... And yeah, I would like it to automatically stop when it hits the end of the file.

Comment: @Malady No, code in questions can't be altered once posted as a general rule. In the future, please just make sure the code you post is working. Arguably I shouldn't have answered, but some aspects were separate from the broken parts, so I could comment on them.